# How to get ResultCodeExtended OPOS?

Tags: c#, epson, escpos, opos

I am trying to print an image on Epson TM-T20II. Here is my code:

```
string path = @"test.bmp";
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    Console.WriteLine("exists");
    OPOSHelper.printer.ErrorEvent += Printer_ErrorEvent; // Do I have to configure this?
    OPOSHelper.printer.SetBitmap(1, PrinterStation.Receipt, path, PosPrinter.PrinterBitmapAsIs, PosPrinter.PrinterBitmapCenter);
    OPOSHelper.printer.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt, "\x1B|1B");                     
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("DOES NOT EXIST!!!");
}
```

When I run it I got the next error:

> Method SetBitmap threw an exception. A class-specific error condition
>   ocurred. the error condition code is available in the
>   ResultCodeExtended property

I want to read the `ResultCodeExtended property` but i cant find how, do I have to configure the `ErrorEvent`? Or how is it suppouse to read it?

Answer (score 0):

`ResultCodeExtended` is a property of `ControlObject`.

Your `OPOSHelper.printer` is probably a library created by someone, you would be using internal `ControlObject` via the library.

If `OPOSHelper.printer` does not expose `ResultCodeExtended`, you can not know it.

Please check the specification of `OPOSHelper.printer`, or the corresponding source code.

Comment: `<br>` Doesn't do anything on this site. You have to enter twice

Comment: @AustinWBryan Thank you for your editing and advice.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code in a try/catch. The SetBitmap function is part of the POS for .NET framework.

See this link to view documentation on the SetBitmap Function:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms843078(v%3dwinembedded.11)

Your try catch should be typecasting the exception to at the very least a POSControlException:

SetBitmap may throw a PosControlException with the following ErrorCodes:

```
Illegal
```

> One of the following conditions has occurred:
>
> The specified station is invalid—it must be either Slip or Receipt.
>
> The specified station does not support printing of bitmaps (that is,
>   the appropriate CapSlpBitmap or CapRecBitmap property is set to
>   false).
>
> The printer is currently in Insertion mode. The printer is currently
>   in Removal mode. The number that is specified for bitmapNumber is less
>   than 1 or greater than 20 and therefore invalid.
>
> The value for width is less than or equal to zero but not set to
>   PrinterBitmapAsIs and therefore invalid.

```
NoExist
```

> fileName was not found.

```
Extended
```

> ExtendedErrorTooBig: The bitmap is either too wide to print without
>   transformation, or it is too big to transform.
>
> ExtendedErrorBadFormat: The specified file is either not a bitmap
>   file, or it is in an unsupported format.

If you set a breakpoint at your catch, you'll see the details about the ResultCodeExtended property, I'm sure.